# TcpClient sometimes seems not to finish a writing before closing/disposing. Why?

Tags: tcp, tcpclient, dispose

given is this simplified code:

```
class SenderFactory
{
  public TcpSender ConnectSender( IPEndPoint ipEndPoint )
  {
    TcpClient client = new TcpClient();
    client.NoDelay = true;
    client.Connect( ipEndPoint );
    return new TcpSender( client );
  }
}

class TcpSender : IDisposable
{
  TcpClient client;
  NetworkStream stream;

  public void TcpSender( TcpClient client )
  {
    this.client = client;
  }

  public void Send( byte[] data )
  {
    stream = client.GetStream();
    stream.Write( data, 0, data.Length );
  }

  public void Dispose()
  {
    stream?.Close();
    stream?.Dispose();
    client?.Close();
    client?.Dispose();  
  }
}

class Test
{
  void Test()
  {
    using(TcpSender sender = factory.ConnectSender( ipEndPoint ))
    {
      // every data is only around 20 bytes
      sender.Send( data1 );
      sender.Send( data2 );
      sender.Send( data3 );
      sender.Send( data4 );
      // Thread.Sleep(10); It always works with this sleep
    }
  }
}
```

I am sending a few commands to the endpoint (The endpoint is a hardware device whose code I have no access to).
The device can only handle one command at a time.

The code works like 80-90% of the time (device receives the data and displays it), but sometimes it just seems it does not receive the data (because it does not display it).
It always works if I do this ugly Thread.Sleep(10) before disposing.

Does anyone have a clue what this could be? Maybe the closing/disposing of the stream/client is too fast in some random cases?
What would be a better approach to fix this?

Thank you!

Comment: We have no idea. If the device is a black box and you don't know the protocol specifications, all you can do is guess, and so can we.

Comment: TCP doesn't lose data. Sleeps in networking code don't solve problems. Something else is wrong.

Comment: That's what I thought as well. So, what COULD be wrong?

Comment: actually, data can be kinda "lost" before it is sent. if socket is closed before all data is sent out, TCP is not required to actually send the data, instead it can just send fin and dispose of all remaining data. i don't know how to do it in java, but there may be a method that blocks the socket untill all data is actually sent. it will be however essentially the sleep method, but with only required delay

Comment: this was pure speculation, which depends on how box implements "only one command at a time". this is not normal for tcp to do this, and the only option i see is to advertize zero receive window if the device is busy processing something or first advertize window of one command and then delay acks, which will also result in sender not sending data while device is busy.